# npm is not installing any packages alerady tried changing npm config settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

i am stuck while installing create-react-app  it says it could be some network settings problem but what

[image: 1]

Comment: Damn that's weird. Have you tried directly running `npx create-react-app my-app` and letting npm install the package throught running this command? If still not working, I would suggest to uninstall & reinstall node ☹️

Comment: Try adding `--verbose` to the output? see what it says

Comment: still its not working can u plse help me get it installed using teamviewer

Comment: i am beginner and learning by myself i want to get it installed any how

Comment: It seems normal on your screen

Comment: but its not installing